# Excel Sorting issue with cell references

Tags: excel, sorting

I am having an issue where sorting on a sheet is causing an issue on another sheet where the data is referenced.
Here is an example to make it easy to understand:
Sheet 1!A1 has a list of random names, Sheet2!A1's formula is "=Sheet1!A1". I am adding new columns to Sheet2 such as B, C and D.
When I sort the values of Column A in Sheet 1, I see the sort order in Sheet2!A reflects the change, but not the columns B,C and D. How can I tie the Columns B,C and D, to column A in Sheet2?
[image]

Thank you in advance,
Gokalp

Comment: Are your additional columns in Sheet 2 "hard coded values" or are they also reference formulas to Sheet1? Perhaps a quick screen shot of your sheet 2 (before and after sorting) will help us see what you mean.

Comment: They are hard coded values, not linked to any cell in Sheet 1, or Sheet 2.

Comment: @user1653604 I don't believe you can do that.  You will need to sort on Sheet2.  Or you could use a VBA routine to do the sorting if you MUST sort only on Sheet1.  There's really nothing to tell Excel that you want to keep columns C:D "attached" to the original entries in Column B.

Comment: Thank you Ron. Looks like I need to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Convert sheet 2 to a table and then use it to sort your data. Highlight the data and then click on Insert on the ribbon at the top and click table. You may need to make a header row. Then sorting will be done on sheet 2.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Blake. That way I can do the sorting in Sheet2, but in my case the sorting will be done in sheet1 for most cases.

Comment: If he is going to sort on sheet2, then there is no need to create a table